# Can anyone tell me commands from which we can jump to any date in a calendar?

Tags: android

public void a(View v)
    {
        Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();

```
    startTime.set(2013,6,25);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/time/"
            + String.valueOf(startTime.getTimeInMillis()));

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    // Use the Calendar app to view the time.
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from API Level 14 you can create appropriate intent:

```
Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
builder.appendPath("time");
ContentUris.appendId(builder, timestamp_in_millis);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setData(builder.build());
startActivity(intent);
```

And following permissions should be added to manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```